# SQL server Date = @date but executionplan xml show it in inequality

Tags: sql-server, indexing, equality, sql-execution-plan, sql-server-2017

So I was trying to guess which missing index SQL Server is going to suggest based on a query I wrote. Please help me understand why this is not considered "equality" by execution plan XML? I am using SQL Server 2017.

I expected this to be considered "equality" and obviously made the wrong guess on the order of missing index creation syntax.

DB name - Stackoverflow2013

Query:

```sql
set statistics io on
declare   @year int = 2008
declare @date nvarchar(10)

while @year <= 2015
begin
    set @date =  cast (@year as nvarchar(6))+ cast('-05-27' as nvarchar(6))
    select
        title,
        cast (CreationDate as date)
    from
        posts
    where
        cast (CreationDate as date) = @date
        and title = 'Tool to diagonalize large matrices'

    set @year = @year + 1
end
```

Missing Index suggestion:

```sql
/*
create NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex_creationdate]
ON [dbo].[Posts] ([Title],[CreationDate])
*/
```

Execution Plan XML:

```xml
<MissingIndexes>
  <MissingIndexGroup Impact="99.9676">
    <MissingIndex Database="[StackOverflow2013]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Posts]">
      <ColumnGroup Usage="EQUALITY">
        <Column Name="[Title]" ColumnId="19" />
      </ColumnGroup>
      <ColumnGroup Usage="INEQUALITY">
        <Column Name="[CreationDate]" ColumnId="8" />
      </ColumnGroup>
    </MissingIndex>
  </MissingIndexGroup>
</MissingIndexes>
```

Comment: What is `CreationDate` in the table and why is `@date` an `nvarchar(10)`?

Comment: @GSerg the purpose was to find all posts on stackoverflow2013 created on the 27th of may between 2008 and 2013. There must be a better way to write this of course, but I am learning querying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming CreationDate is a datetime,  you've got CreationDate wrapped in a transformation that eliminiates the time portion:

```
where
    cast (CreationDate as date) = @date
```

The query can only match on Title, and then must scan all the CreationDates for that Title for the whole day.  There's special support for this particular pattern (explained [here](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/01/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.html)), and internally the expression is transformed into a range predicate on the CreationDate, thus the inequality.

Some caviats for this approach are [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea), and the query is probably better in the form:

```
where CreationDate >= @date
  and CreationDate < dateadd(day,1,@date)
```

Comment: `Since you've got CreationDate wrapped in a non-SARGable expression` - if `CreationDate` is datetime, then it [is sargable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/5203).

Comment: So it is.  Updated answer.

Comment: The range predicate that you get with this dynamic seek is larger than the one you would get with a `>= ... <` that you do yourself though

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you so much, I understood now